# iPhone - In App purchase, no valid products

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, bundle

I continually received the message "No valid Products" when attempting to test the in-app purchase feature in my iPhone/iPad app.  I've checked many lists on the web and was positive that I covered everything.

Answer (score 1):

After many hours of working on this bug I finally discovered what the actual problem was and therefore, the solution.

Yes, you do NOT need to submit a binary in order to test the in-app purchase.  However, since I could not figure out what the problem was, I decided to submit my binary anyway.  I figured, I've done everything else what could it hurt.

So, Here is what I did:

1. Archived my app
2. Clicked the "Distribute" button
3. Selected "Submit to the iOS App Store" and clicked Next
4. Click Next again to log into iTunes Connect

BAMM!

I received the message:   "No identities are available for signing"

What?!!! What does that mean?

This was a very good message in order for me to narrow down the problem.  This told me that I couldn't submit my app to the app store, hmmm, so I thought I should double-check the bundle id.  Looks good in the app, what about in iTunes connect?  I logged in to iTunes Connect and went to Manage apps and selected my app.

uh,oh!  what?  I had the wrong bundle id?  how come?

Well, it was because when I created this new version of my app in the latest Xcode I decided to create a brand new project and I changed the name of the project and of course it had a different bundle id.  ahha!

Next step was to change the bundle id to the old one (This has no bearing on the name of the Xcode project)  Problem was that when I selected my Target, the bundle id had in grey the name of my new Xcode project at the end and it wouldn't allow me to delete the name.  I googled the issue and here is what you need to do:

Open your -info.plist and edit the Bundle identifier.  Delete the suffix ${PRODUCT_NAME}.  Now you can set your bundle id correctly.

That was it!  once I set the bundle id my in-app purchase was working!  YAY!

TIP: I got fooled into thinking that since the Product ID for the In-App Purchase Item (com.name.newprojectname) matched my new bundle id (com.name.newprojectname), that all was ok.  nope.  you can put anything you want in the product id.  When you run your application in Xcode and you are trying to make an In-app purchase, it should check that the bundle id of your application that you are running in Xcode exists in iTunes connect and display a message when they don't match.  That would have saved me SO much time.

Finally I can submit my app to the app store.

I hope that this solution has saved some other fellow developers some time and hair pulling.